# Show that $af∧bg=(ab)f∧g$

Tags: manifolds, exterior-algebra

Let $v$ be vector space. For $a$ and $b$ are in IR, $f$ is in $A_{k}(V)$ and $g$ is in $A_{l}(V)$

Show that $af∧bf=(ab)f∧g$

Here Will I use the definition of wedge product? Is ti right? How to use? Thank you.

Comment: This is definition bashing.  Use the formula that shows how to reorder a wedge (there will be powers of $(-1)$ etc. in it).  Bring out the constants and then rearrange it again so the constants are outside.

Comment: @muzzlator which formula? Please can you solve this clearly? I have learnt newly. So I dont know many things. Thank you.

Comment: Posted an answer.  As you can see, there's not much to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra as a reference

Here $$(f \wedge  g) (x_1, \dots, x_{k+l})  =  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} sgn(\sigma) f(x_{\sigma (1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(k)}) g( x_{\sigma(k+1)},  \dots, x_{\sigma(k+l)}) $$

$$(af \wedge  bg) (x_1, \dots, x_{k+l})  =  \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} sgn(\sigma) a f(x_{\sigma (1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(k)}) b g( x_{\sigma(k+1)},  \dots, x_{\sigma(k+l)}) = ab (f \wedge  g) (x_1, \dots, x_{k+l})$$

Comment: Hmm ok I know this formula. But I cannot realize to apply this formula for solution. Thank you.

Comment: No probs.  That is the problem with some of these 'basic' math exercises, it feels like you're not doing anything at all.  I'd rather set my beginner exercises to do stuff that's actually useful or interesting.

Comment: I think it is one of those cases, @muzzlator, where it is important to both know this rule and that it is essentially trivial. You can teach the rule, but it can sometimes be a better pedagogic approach to let your students discover that it is so simple for themselves.